# Createing a php/js toggle for a list of links

Tags: javascript, php, html, toggle

so I got in some truble with some php code so what I want to obtain is this, a toggle link to the same page, the toggle when is pressed will show a list of link generated using PHP, the links are to download some documents from the server, sorry in advance for using torrent links but I had no idee of what else, Also i want to mention that I am not using these to create any type of illegal content website, so here is the example in html:

```
       <html>
       <head>

       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <script type="text/javascript">

           function toggle_visibility(id) {
               var e = document.getElementById(id);
               if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
               else e.style.display = 'block';
           }

       </script>
       <style> 
       #foo1 {
           list-style-type: none;
           padding-bottom:10px;
           display: none;
       }
       #foo2 {
           list-style-type: none;
           padding-bottom:10px;
           display: none;
       }
       </style>
       </head>
       <body>
       <h3>Programs</h3>

       <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo1');">Movies</a>

       <div id="foo1">
           <ul style="padding-bottom:15px;list-style-type: none;">
               <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/the-official-uk-top-40-singles-chart-15-06-2014-t9225052.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Movie~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

               </li>
               <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/the-official-uk-top-40-singles-chart-15-06-2014-t9225052.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Movie~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

               </li>
               <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/the-official-uk-top-40-singles-chart-15-06-2014-t9225052.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Movie~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>

       <br><a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo2');">Music</a>
       <div id="foo2">
       <ul style="padding-bottom:15px;list-style-type: none;">
               <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://kickass.to/game-of-thrones-s04e10-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-rartv-t9225859.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Muzic~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

               </li>
               <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/game-of-thrones-s04e10-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-rartv-t9225859.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Muzic~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>

               </li>
               <li style="padding-bottom:15px;"><a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://kickass.to/game-of-thrones-s04e10-720p-hdtv-x264-killers-rartv-t9225859.html" onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> _Muzic~2014-06-16-1808-name-muzic--1.0.1-4035-g0d107d0~Host</a>
                    </li>
           </ul>
       </div>


       </body></html>
```

And what I have done in PHP by now is this:

```
       <?



        if (isset($_POST['password']))
        {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $goodPass = '******';
        if ($password == $goodPass)
            $_SESSION['loggedIn']=1;
        }
        if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) 
            showPasswordForm();
         else
        {
               $install_links = getDirectory(".");
               rsort($install_links);
               $oldPrefix = "";
                   foreach ($install_links as $key => $val) 
               {
                $strip_val = strip_tags($val);

                $prefix = explode("~",$strip_val);
                //echo "Prefix:|".$prefix[0]."|</br>";
                            if (strcmp($prefix[0],$oldPrefix)!=0)
                    echo <<<EOT </div> <a href='#'            onclick="toggle_visibility('".$prefix[0]."');"> "".$prefix[0].""</a><div id="".$prefix[0]."">EOT;
        $oldPrefix = $prefix[0];
            echo '<li style="padding-bottom:15px">'.$val.'</li><br/>';
    }

}

       function getDirectory( $path = '.', $level = 0 ){ 

           $echoData = false;

           $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://";
           $root_folder_url_prefix = $protocol.".....";

           $ignore = array( 'cgi-bin', '.', '..','WHat.app.dSYM' ); 
           // Directories to ignore when listing output. Many hosts 
           // will deny PHP access to the cgi-bin. 

           $dh = @opendir( $path ); 
           // Open the directory to the handle $dh 

           $install_links = array();

           while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dh ) ) ){ 
           // Loop through the directory 

               if( !in_array( $file, $ignore ) ){ 
               // Check that this file is not to be ignored 

                   $spaces = str_repeat( '&nbsp;', ( $level * 4 ) ); 
                              // Just to add spacing to the list, to better 
                   // show the directory tree. 

                   if( is_dir( "$path/$file" ) ){ 
                   // Its a directory, so we need to keep reading down... 

                       if ( $echoData) 
        echo "<strong>$spaces $file</strong><br />"; 
                       $subarray = getDirectory( "$path/$file", ($level+1) ); 

               $install_links = array_merge($install_links, $subarray);
                       // Re-call this same function but on a new directory. 
                       // this is what makes function recursive. 

                   } else { 
               if (strstr($file,".ipa"))
                {
        //echo ">>".$file."<<";
        $filename = str_replace(".ipa","",$file);
        $plist_path = substr($path,2);
                $plist_path = str_replace("/","~",$plist_path);
        $plist_location =            $root_folder_url_prefix.$plist_path."~".$filename.".plist";
        $link = '<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url='.$plist_location.'"  onclick="this.color=#FF0000;"> '.$plist_path.'-'.$filename.'</a>';

                if ( $echoData) 
            echo "$spaces $link<br/>";

        array_push($install_links,$link);

                    }
               else             
               {
                           //   echo "$spaces $file<br />"; 
                           // Just print out the filename 
                       }
                   } 

               } 

           } 

           closedir( $dh ); 
           // Close the directory handle 

           return $install_links;
       }




       function showPasswordForm()
       {
        ?>
       <center>
       <form action="index.php" method="post">
       <table>
       <tr><td>User:</td>  <td> <input type="text" name="user" /></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Password:</td> <td> <input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
       <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>           </tr>
       </table>
       </form> 
       </center>
        <?
       }

       ?>
```

And as you may see I have not yet implemented the js into the php....

Comment: What is the exact problem you're experiencing?

Comment: If you run the html example you will see what I wanted to do, and if you run the php you will see that it does not work, furthermore I think the js is wrongly implemented and also the html.

Comment: I think the least you could do is specify the error messages your receive, tell us what you want to accomplish (in words) and what you get instead. 

From your post it is not clear at all what you are trying to do. You mention a JavaScript toggle and a php generated list. Which one of these things is not working? You should specify 1 problem you experience. If you have problems on many levels, cut them down and ask separate questions so you can focus one question on one problem.

Comment: So what I am trying to achive is this, I have a folder, lets say Folder1 and in this folder I have 3 subfolders lets say Subfolder1, Subfolder2 and Subfolder3 and each of these 3 subfolders I have 5 files that need to be downloaded. I want to create 3 links that are toggles for the downloading links. So I will have 3 toggle links called Subfolder1, Subfolder2 and Subfolder3. aND when you click them using a js function you change the display property of the subfolder for each of the folder links. So if you click Subfolder1 it will expand and show the download links for the 5 documents.

Comment: And the name of one file from the Subfolder1 is testDownload1.exe, so the link will have the name of the parent folder concatenated with the name of the file that will be downloaded. So the name will be: Subfolder1_testDownload1.exe

Comment: The problem is that I need to echo the js code and the css code into the php.

Comment: And these is the js function that I want to implement on the Folder1, Folder2 and Folder3:
          function toggle_visibility(id) {
               var e = document.getElementById(id);
               if (e.style.display == 'block') e.style.display = 'none';
               else e.style.display = 'block';
           }